# Same Titanium code base for Android & Iphone

Tags: android, iphone, titanium

I have been trying to create a single codebase for both Iphone & Android for a intermediate level app. ( 4 tabs, multiple windows, maps etc.) using itanium 2.1 API.
However, I have found that things on Android platform dont work as smoothly or willingly as on Iphone epsecially tableviews & UI elemnts. The UI responsiveness on Android is also sluggish.
The kitchen sink examples are pretty straightforward. I am looking at an enterprise ready app which has to be maintained for atleast next couple of years.
Has anybody worked on similar lines with platform quirks and been successful in creating fully functional iOS & Android apps from SAME codebase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Titanium is not meant for 1 codebase for all. You do need to rewrite stuff for every OS. However, some app developers claim to have reused 95% of its code. So only 5% of the code is OS specific. But I am sure their code is full with if-elses.

What I recommend doing, to be able to maintain it properly, without thousands of if-else constructions, is build a single backend core, and write code specifically for UI related matters per OS. This way, you have some UI related code for Android, UI related code for iOS and 1 core working for both.

Since Android and iOS differ a lot, writing a single codebase will make sure you can never use OS specific features (like android hardware menu button, or iOS NavigationGroup), and will let the UI look non-intuitive.

Comment: This pretty much answers my query a smy brief was to use OS specific UI features and try to manage it in a single codebase.

Answer (score 4):

I'm having a lot of success using the compile-time CommonJS mechanism for having a root view that then has os-specific capabilities.

For instance, my os-independent view might be **ui/MyView.js** :

```
var createAddButton = require("ui/MyView.AddButton");

var MyView = function() {
    var self = Ti.UI.createWindow();
    createAddButton(self, function() { alert('ADD!'); });
    return self;
};

module.exports = MyView;
```

Then, I create os-specific functions to handle it:

**iphone/ui/MyView.AddButton.js**

```
module.exports = function(view, addHandler) {
    var addButton = Titanium.UI.createButton({
        systemButton: Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.ADD
    });

    addButton.addEventListener("click", addHandler);

    view.rightNavButton = addButton;
};
```

**android/ui/MyView.AddButton.js**

```
module.exports = function(view, addHandler) {
    view.activity.onCreateOptionsMenu = function(e){
        var menuItem = e.menu.add({ title: "Add" });
        menuItem.addEventListener("click", addHandler);
    }; 
};
```

The CommonJS system they have implemented will pick the appropriate version of **MyView.AddButton.js** so that the button is added to the right place.  It allows for the majority of the view to be the same, but the os-specific things to be separated properly.

Comment: +1 for using CommonJS, which is the Titanium recommended way to do this

Comment: Thanks, will keep this mind for new apps but for existing app, it is too tangled to implement this right away.